# groovy change bean variables using properties

Tags: groovy

Is there a way in groovy to do something like:

```
class Person{
    def name, surname
}
public void aMethod(anoherBean){
    def bean = retrieveMyBean()
    p.properties = anoherBean.properties
}
```

The property *properties* is final, is there another way to do this shortcut?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Is there any reason?

Comment: Because I'm too lazy to write all the set methods :P. 
No, seriously the object is created in another point of the application, and I want to set all the properties, also if I don't know the type of the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`properties` is a virtual property; you have to call the individual setters. Try this:

```
def values = [name: 'John', surname: 'Lennon']
for( def entry : values.entries() ) {
    p.setProperty( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
}
```

Or, using MOP:

```
Object.class.putAllProperties = { values -> 
    for( def entry : values.entries() ) {
        p.setProperty( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
    }
}

Person p = new Person();
p.putAllProperties [name: 'John', surname: 'Lennon']
```

**[EDIT]** To achieve what you want, you must loop over the properties. [This blog post](https://lbroudoux.wordpress.com/2009/05/04/copying-groovy-object-properties-back-and-forth/) describes how to do that:

```
def copyProperties(def source, def target){
   target.metaClass.properties.each{
      if (source.metaClass.hasProperty(source, it.name) && it.name != 'metaClass' && it.name != 'class')
         it.setProperty(target, source.metaClass.getProperty(source, it.name))
   }
}
```

Comment: the code wasn't complete, check now. Can I do what I'm trying?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any special reason then just use named parameters

```
def p = new Person(name: 'John', surname: 'Lennon')
```

---

After question being updated

```
static copyProperties(from, to) {
    from.properties.each { key, value ->
        if (to.hasProperty(key) && !(key in ['class', 'metaClass']))
            to[key] = value
    }
}
```